# What TCP protocols are usable for client to client communication?

Tags: tcp, client-side, p2p, instant-messaging

Manytimes clients ask for features like instant messaging (IM) and other client-to-client (P2P) communication for their web apps. Typically how is this done in normal web browsers? For example I've seen demos of [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) (and Gmail) that are able to IM from a regular browser. Is this via HTTP? Or does XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) provide the necessary backend for such communication?

More than anything I wonder how can a server "wake up" the remote client, lets say for sending an IM? Or does the client have to keep "polling" the message server for new IMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the browser will poll the server for new messages. One approach that is often done to make this more efficient is the '[long poll](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/the-long-poll-implementing-ajax-chat-with-comet/)' (see also [this link](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/16/more-on-long-polling/)) - the server responds immediately if it has anything; otherwise, it waits, keeping the connection open for a while. If a message comes in, it immediately wakes up and sends it, otherwise it comes back with a 'nope, check back' after a few tens of seconds. The client them immediately redials to go back into the long-polling state.

Comment: Any idea of other protocols such as RTMP? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol

Comment: Other protocols tend not to be supported by JavaScript. If you're using flash you can open raw TCP sockets and do whatever you like, though.